# After the click on Community standard pages button it automatically logged in as Guest User

Tags: customer-community

I've created a community, and using the standard login/forgot password pages to login into community.

When i click on forgot password link on login page, it redirect to forgot Password page.as below [image]

When i click on cancel button, it logged in automatically by guest user. 
[image]

It should not happen.

Please suggest the what is going wrong here.

Comment: are you using a lightning community template?

Comment: @glls I'm using SF Tab + Vf Template and overiding the standard pages by custom VF pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check you "**Community Home**" setting under "**Pages**".

Is it linked to a public page on Site.com?

Forgot Password "**Cancel**" button by default links to Community Home Page.

You can override the default page by setting it to custom VF page